# Checking for integer and creating error message in terminal - not crash the program

Tags: java, terminal, boolean

I am working on a program that allows me to move a pen, making a mark on a canvas. At the moment, I have a method called convertToInteger in class "MyInput" (which in the class with my methods I've referred to as "reader"), which converts a string into an integer.

```
public int convertToInteger(String word)
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(word);
    }
```

I've then tied this into my method, converting a string input into an integer.

```
case "move":
    int distance = reader.convertToInteger(command.get(1));
    brush.move(distance);
    break;
```

Thus, in my program I can type "move 100" and the brush move 100 pixels. The code, in its current state, crashes with an exception error if I tried typing a non-integer; e.g. "move here".

In "MyInput" class, I created a boolean method that checks to see if it's a integer or not using 'try' and 'catch':

```
public boolean isAnInteger(String word)
   {
       boolean ok;
       try {
           Integer.parseInt(word);
           ok = true;
       }
       catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
           // Non-integer string.
           ok = false;
       }
       return ok;
   }
```

Then tried implementing it in my code:

```
case "move":
     int distance = reader.convertToInteger(command.get(1));
     if (reader.isAnInteger(command.get(1)) == true){
              brush.move(distance);
     }
      else {
              printError();
     }
     break;
```

When I run the code and type something like "move here" in the terminal, it throws an exception so clearly its bypassing my code - but typing "move 100" or any other valid integer works.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instructions are in the wrong order.  Your are attempting to parse, then checking if it can be parsed.  You should really check first, then try to parse.

Comment: Ha ... so I did. Schoolboy error. Thanks for the answer. Upvoted and answered.